# Can't use BackgroundImage property on a Button

Tags: c#, button

I'm trying to set an image as button background as follows:

```
button.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.blue;
```

But I get an error that says:

> 'Button does not contain a definition for 'backgroundImage' and no accessible extention method 'BackgroundImagew accepting a first argument of type 'Button' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What is the type of `button`?

Comment: Can you provide us some `code` examples?

Answer (score 0):

```
   button.Background = Brushes.Blue;
```

Is this the result you are trying to gather